Smooth transition of mysql server from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS
This issue is all around the internet (ex.: here, or here) without a definite solution. Last time I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu server and after one day of malfunction, I had to roll back to 18.04 LTS (ALWAYS make backups, my VPS provider has snapshot backups) because I couldn't put mysql server working.
How to smoothly update mySql server when upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?
Simply running, as instructed
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade -d

will crash mysql server.
Any tips for a smooth transition? Stop the mysql server perhaps before upgrading?

Silly question, but why not simply set up a new web server with 20.04 (or 24.04), dump the MySQL tables from the previous system, and import into the new? Upgrading MySQL is often tricky due to a lot of changes in the underlying libraries and the deprecations that occur with every major version

@matigo because I have a LOT of stuff (apps, runners, crontabs, webservices, etc.) running in this server.

@matigo wait, do you mean fully uninstalling mysql server before upgrading ubuntu and then installing mysql server from scratch after upgrading ubuntu?

It is generally “a bad idea” to treat a server as a pet. If the system is not replaceable in the space of an hour or two, then upgrades will always be considered too risky to embark upon, particularly now that 18.04 is unsupported by many third-party entities.

@matigo I don't have the money nor the resources to have another server running in parallel "just in case"

I just did a clean install of 18.04 with MySQL server. I upgraded to 20.04, and the MySQL server works without any problems. So, it really depends on your configuration.

@matigo I applied to Ubuntu Pro, thus Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is supported till 2030 :)
